# Solve for the argument to a function that will produce a particular return value

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, solver

Suppose I have a Python function `y` of `x`, where `x` must be a number, and the return value is always a number.  `y` is a mathematical function of one variable.

Is there a function in Python (i.e., in `numpy`, `scipy`, etc.) that would be able to solve for the particular value(s) for `x` that produces a desired return value -- using, e.g., gradient descent?

I'm looking for a `magic_function` that would do something like this:

```
>>> from my_module import y
>>> from magic_package import magic_function
>>> desired = 10
>>> x = magic_function(y, desired)
>>> y(x)
10
```

Comment: Perhaps you want a [root finding function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root)?

Comment: @Evert well, that would work for the special case of `desired = 0`.  i think what i want is `scipy.optimize.minimize`, where the `fun` passed to `minimize` is `y(x) - desired`.

Comment: Of course not: `x = scipy.optimize.root(y-desired, xguess)` and it works for whatever your `desired` value is.

Comment: @Evert ah, good call.  yeah, i guess either of our options works.  i forgot that for mine to work it'd have to be `abs(y(x) - desired)`.

Comment: `y - desired` is probably the wrong form, but you can easily wrap that: `def newy(x): return y(x) - desired` or similar. And then pass `newy` to `scipy.optimize.root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your function y(x) so that it's offset by the desired value. Here's a simple demo of the long way to do that:

```
def y(x):
    return x*x

def offset_function(f, desired=0):
    def newf(x):
        return f(x) - desired
    return newf

y9 = offset_function(y, 9)

for x in range(5):
    print x, y(x), y9(x)
```

**output**

```
0 0 -9
1 1 -8
2 4 -5
3 9 0
4 16 7
```

However, it's simpler just to use a `lambda`:

```
y9 = lambda x: y(x) - 9
```

You can pass that to your root-finder like this:

```
scipy.optimize.root(lambda x: y(x) - 9, xguess)
```

Comment: i guess i'd just point out that there are a ton of functions in `scipy.optimize` aside from `root` that can accomplish this general functionality: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html.

Comment: @dbliss: Fair enough. I don't know scipy; I use mpmath.